# RSpec put, post, get, delete, patch behave the same way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

Suppose that I specify resource routes like this:
`resources :projects, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]`

Normally in a controller test we trigger an action  of `:create` by simply doing:

`post(:create)`

And when we do this with `delete(:create)` it should throw a `routing error` exception. But it doesn't. It works also with `get(:create)`, `put(:create)`, `patch(:create)`.

What is the explanation for this behavior?  Is this normal with controller specs?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior for controller specs. The methods `get`, `post`, `patch`, `put`, `delete` and `head` are defined in [ActionController::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html). Each method simulates the respective HTTP request, and calls the action in the controller being tested. So e.g.:

```
post(:create)
```

simulates a POST and handles it by calling the `create` action. You might have other actions that take a POST; to test them you'd replace `:create` with the action name.

Note that the router is not involved. Routing is not the responsibility of the controller, and thus the controller specs do not test the behavior of the router. To write unit tests for routes, use [routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/routing-specs).

Calling `delete(:create)` means "simulate a DELETE and handle it with the `create` action". Which doesn't make much sense. But nothing stops you from creating a route that sends `DELETE /resource/:id` to the `create` action, if that's what you want (Note: that's probably not what you want).